# Смена шрифта "на лету"

Tags: android

В меню настройки приложения есть актвити, где пользователь выбирает тип шрифта, его цвет и размер; Но все эти настройки начинают действовать только после того, как текущее активити закрывается, т.е. выбираем параметры, выходим из настроек и только тогда настройки начинают действовать. Это не очень красиво...
Хотелось бы, чтобы выбирая шрифт из списка и нажимая кнопку "Применить", (или вообще не нажимая, а по факту "OnItemSelected") шрифты на экране менялись сразу же.

В какую сторону копать?

Comment: можно перезапустить активность с новыми значениями просто и все

Comment: что-то не получается у меня это: пробовал finish();
startActivity(getIntent()); и просто recreate(). Экран моргает, но ничего не исзменяется...

Comment: добавил ответ, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ - отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Можно два варианта: записать в память устройства значение характеристики либо перезаписать значение пункта стиля. Я предпочитаю использовать первый вариант решения.

При выборе цвета/размера/типа шрифта вы в память устройства записываете значение выбранной характеристики. То есть у цвета например string тип данных, и вы его записываете в память устройства, так же поступаем и с остальными характеристиками. Дальше при старте каждой активности в функции `onCreate()` мы проверяем наличие этих записей в памяти, и если они есть то применяем значение. Так записываем в память устройства к примеру значение цвета:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("my_app_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString( "color", "color_code" );
editor.commit();
```

и дальше проверяем при старте активности значение этой записи и ее наличие:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("my_app_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(settings.getString("color", "").length !=0){
// применяем цвет тексту
}
...
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

вот [тут](https://www.fandroid.info/sharedpreferences-sohranenie-dannyh-v-postoyannoe-hranilishhe-android/) написано про работу с хранилищем в приложении или [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php). И дальше при нажатии на кнопку типа "Применить настройки" вы вызываете функцию:

```
recreate();
```

и ваша активность запустится с новыми значениями. Так же вам нужно будет проверять значения ваших настроек в каждой активности. Так же есть вариант [создания](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor) своей темы с выбранными значениями настроек шрифта и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758942/how-to-create-a-custom-theme-and-use-it-in-android-application) еще статья.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сейчас уже нет времени на проверку, а завтра отпишусь.))

Comment: Спасибо за то, что помогли определить правильное направление действий! Весь фокус был в том, что при обновлении, инициализировалась переменная со значением по умолчанию, поэтому перезагрузка активити ничего не давала))). Присвоил этой переменной значение из сохраненного в память и всё получилось!

Comment: Еще один вопрос, может что -то подскажете: 

Пользователь с помощью SeekBar выбирает нужный цвет (RGB) для текста. После выбора, этот цвет текста должен быть установлен для всего текста в приложении. Как это сделать программно?

Я понимаю, что можно сделать несколько цветовых тем в stiles.xml и потом их применять. Но вся проблема в том, что мне не нужны предустановленные темы. Мне нужно чтобы цвет выбирал, с помощью "ползунков" сам пользователь.

Ну и еще: прописывать смену цвета теста каждого view в коде вручную, тоже решение не очень...